# Cache and iterate over an array of associative arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I want to cache my mysql results to decrease database load.
To cache results I am using the following function:

```
$cached = $this->getMemCacheX($name);

if ($cached === false)
{
    $res = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($res === false) exit('Database failure.');
    if ($fetch === "assoc")
    {
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    }
    else if ($fetch === "array")
    {
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) === 0) $data = 0;
    $cr = $this->saveMemCacheX($name, $data);
    if ($cr === false) exit('Cache failure.');
    return $data;
}
else
{
    return $cached;
}
```

My problem is that I need to save and load a result set over wich I used to iterate using a while(mysql_fetch_assoc())-Loop like:

```
$res = mysql_query("...");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
...
}
```

Now I need to store my results in the cache, but because I can't store $res I need to fetch the results first.

How is it possible to iterate through an already fetched result set? I tried out a few foreach-Loops but didn't find a solution.

How should I fetch the results in order to get an array of associative arrays from the database results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mysql_fetch_* functions fetch data one row at a time. They do not return the entire result set. For that, you have to loop over the result set and build your own array:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // fetch as an associative array
   $data[] = $row;
}
```